# Each time I run a java app with Android Studio on my motorola G9 with USB debug I get Invalid ID 0x00000000 error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, smartphone

Here is a snapshot of the error:

[image]

What does this error mean?

Comment: Do you mean an Android app?  Android Studio is not an app.

Comment: I mean by runing a Java app on USB debug with Android Studio @StephenC

Comment: It means that your Android app is trying to use a resource with ID zero .... which is not a valid resource id.  We can't say any more without more information.   Except that it could be a bug in the app.

Comment: I was thinking that this error was actually interfering with my app behavior. But actually, it was the fact that Motorolla G9 didn't have a Magnetometer sensor that resulted in the problem. I just assumed that all brand new phones must have such sensor. @StephenC see this: https://www.reddit.com/r/MotoG/comments/n75df7/why_are_so_many_motorola_phones_missing_the/

Comment: Like I said ... a bug in your app :-)